# how do you say starting something and coming back to it until it is completed professionally

Tags: phrase-requests

If as an example a teacher gives you a 10 page paper due in a week. You start the project when you are assigned it. However, you can not finish it in a single session. Therefore, you continue working on the essay at a later date. However, you do not finish the essay in that session either. This process continues until the essay is finished.

How would you suggest utilizing this in a professional tone.

Comment: People rarely finish an assigned piece of work in an uninterrupted period of time from start to finish. In your example, somebody would normally just say, "I finished the work in a week." What are you actually trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is described as working **[in stages](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/in%20stages)**:

> I wrote the 10-page paper **in stages** over a week.

If you wrote a section at a time, you might say that you developed the work **[piecemeal](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piecemeal)**. If many sessions were required, you might say that the gradual process occurred **[incrementally](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incrementally)**

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing, not supplanting, [Chemomechanics's good answer](/a/480042/3461): [*in fits and starts*](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/05/fits-and-starts.html)